# React expo allowed redirect urls

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, authentication, expo

I am currently trying to use descope on my react expo app.   This works great for web but breaks when i use it on my iPhone.   I know this is failing due to the redirect url for the app running on my phone is not in my `Approved Domains` list.

From the reading i did i tried adding the below in my config.
`{ scheme: "myTestApp" }`

Then i tried adding `myTestApp` as a allowed domain but it doesn't seem to help.  Am i missing something?